# 2 file upload controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file-upload

I have 2 file upload controller I have problem when both of them have files one hasFile value equal true and other equal false can someone help me.

```
if (fuPDFDoc.HasFile)
{
    String fileName = fuPDFDoc.FileName;
    savePathPDF_Resouce += fileName;

    fuPDFDoc.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(savePathPDF_Resouce));
}

if (fupdfVocabularyURL.HasFile)
{
    String fileName = fupdfVocabularyURL.FileName;
    savePathPDF_Vocab += fileName;
    fupdfVocabularyURL.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(savePathPDF_Vocab));
}

r.PdfDocURL = savePathPDF_Resouce.ToString();
r.pdfVocabularyURL = savePathPDF_Vocab.ToString();
r.ResourceID = Resoursce.Insert(r);
```

Comment: Is your upload control inside an update panel?

Comment: no,is not but inside light bpx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to refer directly to the files collection, e.g. like this:

```
HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;

for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
{
    HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];              
    if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("MyFiles") + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));                      
    }              
}
```